# how to make a greedy dimension reduction with support vector machine package "e1071"

Tags: r, svm

Here is paper said she make a greedy dimension reduction with support vector machine by searches for the one compound that permitted the best classification of fungal species and functional groups.I want implement the SVM in r with package e1071.  I now first I need built a mode using training and testing subset. But I have no idea how to make the  dimension reduction by adding compounds on by one to the mode. The compounds is features and fungi are y response.

following the description in the paper:

"A greedy dimension reduction algorithm was used to reduce the number of compounds taken into consideration. The algorithm (zu Castell, 2013) is based on multiclass discrimination via support-vector-machines (libsvm in multiclass classification mode with Gaussian kernel; Chang and Lin, 2011). To estimate prediction accuracy, cross-validation was performed by using one-third of the data for training and the remaining two-thirds for prediction (10,000 randomly chosen iterations). The algorithm searches for the one compound that permitted the best classification of fungal species and functional groups. In the next step a second compound is determined, which, in combination with the first one, gave the best classification accuracy. This procedure is repeated adding one compound in each step. The subset of compounds providing maximal prediction accuracy was then used in the further analysis. A PCA was conducted, and data were projected on the first and second PC. The final discrimination was done applying again multiclass support vector machine classification within the plane spanned by the first two PCs. To determine the parameters of the support vector machine, 10-fold cross-validation has been applied. This procedure resulted in a list of compounds based on the maximum prediction accuracy (see footnotes of Table 1)."

```
Fungal groups and species   Prediction probability by chemotyping (%)a
Ectomycorrhizae 99.6
C. geophilum    58.0
L. bicolor  58.6
P. involutus – MAJ  83.2
P. involutus – NAU  79.7

Pathogens   89.5
A. mellea   76.6
P. squarrosa    80.9
V. longisporum  76.1

Saprophytes 90.5
S. rugosoannulata   58.3
T. viride   82.1
```

Probability calculated from the selection of compounds with the maximum prediction accuracy. Compounds used to predict the functional fungal groups selected in this order: cadina-1,4-diene, pentanol, α-bergamotene, 3-methyl-1-butanol, methyl 2-furoate, α-muurolene, hexanol, curcumene, 3,5-dimethylanisole, 2-pentylfuran, 2-methyl-1-butanol, zingiberene, epizonaren, caryophyllene, β-selinene, and γ-selinene. Compounds used to predict the fungal species selected in this order: δ-cadinene, 3-octanone, β-cubebene, hexanol, β-sesquiphellandrene, methyl 2-furoate, pentanol, curcumene, geosmin, 1S-cis-calamenene, linalool, and cadina-1,4-diene.

Comment: This approach is called sequential forward search ~ sfs. It is a common feature selection wrapper. It is implemented in several r packages. Caret and mlr libraries both implement it. The dimension reduction after feature selection makes little sense to me and I doubt it can improve model performance.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just found Caret can make a feature selection. But I still wondering how the paper works. The strategy in the paper meet my need best.